# problem with sql query of a Crystal Report

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

When I create a new command of a report that looks like that

```
select e.x, a.x, a.y
from Table1 t,
     table2 a
where a.z = e.z
  and a.xx = form1.ComboBox1.Text
```

it generates an error. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Can you display the error message too?

Comment: DataBase ConnectorError'DAO Error Code0*bf5
Source DAO.DataBase
Description Trop peu de parametres.1 attendu

Comment: can you post the code that creates the command

Comment: Are you mixing up your 'e' and 't' variables? 'e' isn't defined in your sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your columns need to have different names to each other - at present, the first two columns are both called x. Also, if your ComboBox has multiple values, you need to use an IN condition, not an =. Try changing the query to look like:

```
select e.x e_x, a.x a_x, a.y
from Table1 e,
     table2 a
where a.z = e.z
  and a.xx IN (form1.ComboBox1.Text)
```

Comment: That's my Query but it does not work
select e.Code_col, a.Niveau_att, a.Niveau_obs from Entretien e, App_comp_metier a where a.N_entretien = e.n_entretien and a.Comp_metier IN (Etat2.ComboBox2.Text)

Comment: yes:
DataBase ConnectorError'DAO Error Code0*bf5 
Source DAO.DataBase 
Description Trop peu de parametres.1 attendu

Comment: That appears to be the same error as reported in the comments to the question. The message translates as "Too few parameters" - have any values been set in the ComboBox?